# How to show selected tab based on # in URI?

Tags: javascript, jquery, uri

I am using jQuery to show content in an ID based on nav links are clicked. Can someone tell me how to make it so when going to http://domain.com/mypage.php#section2 will show the contents of a div that contains #section2?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will display an element where the hash matches the id.

```
var hash = window.location.hash;

if (hash) {
   $(hash).show();
}
```

Comment: Thanks! How can I make sure that it only detects a certain ID? For example, I also need to make it so it adds a selected class to the nav button. Is there a way to make it so if #section2 or #section3 is entered in the URL, it will add a class to those nav elements, but if #blahblah is entered it would ignore it?

Comment: @Cofey Yes, you could have an array of allowed elements, or simply validate with a regular expression, something like `/#section\d+$/` should do it.